# numpy conditional format of elements

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pyqtgraph

I have a 3D numpy array and want to change a particular element based on a conditional test of another element. (The applications is to change the 'alpha' of a RGBA image array to play with the transparency in a 3D pyqtgraph image - should ideally be pretty fast).

```
a= np.ones((2,4,5),dtype=np.int) #create a ones array
a[0,0,0] = 3 #change a few values
a[0,2,0] = 3
a[1,2,0] = 3
print(a)
>>>[[[3 1 1 1 1]
  [1 1 1 1 1]
  [3 1 1 1 1]]

 [[1 1 1 1 1]
  [1 1 1 1 1]
  [3 1 1 1 1]]]
```

Now I want to conditionally test the first element of the lowest dimension(??) and then change the last element based on the result.

```
if a[0,:,:] > 1:   #this does not work - for example only - if first element > 1
    a[3,:,:]=255   #then change the last element in the same dimension to 255

print(a) #this is my idealized result
>>>[[[3 1 1 1 255]
  [1 1 1 1 1]
  [3 1 1 1 255]]

 [[1 1 1 1 1]
  [1 1 1 1 1]
  [3 1 1 1 255]]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to do the trick:

```
mask = a[:,:,0] > 1

a[:,:,4][mask] = 255
```

So the indexing just needed to be a little different and then it's just standard practice of applying a mask.

*edit*
@Ophion showed this is much better written as:

```
a[mask,:,-1] = 255
```

Comment: More concisely: `a[mask,:,4] = 255` or `a[mask,:,-1] = 255`.